# NSURLSession cancel Task

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, nsurlsession

I create new NSURLSession with following configs

```
 if (!self.session) {
            NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:[self uniquieIdentifier]];
            config.discretionary = NO;
            self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
        }
```

and on after pressing a button I am trying to stop all current download tasks.

```
[[[self session] delegateQueue] setSuspended:YES];
[[self session] invalidateAndCancel];
```

Nevertheless I get responses in delegate method didFinishDownloadingToURL, and I am pretty sure that no new sessions or download task are created after this point. How to stop all task from happening?

Answer (score 16):

I do not reccommend to use invalidateAndCancel method cause the queue and its identifier keeps invalidated and cannot be reused untill you reset the whole device.

[NSURLSession class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/invalidateAndCancel)

I use this code to cancel all pending tasks.

```
- (void) cancelDownloadFiles
{

    [self.session getTasksWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *dataTasks, NSArray *uploadTasks, NSArray *downloadTasks) {

        for (NSURLSessionTask *_task in downloadTasks)
        {
            [_task cancel];

            id<FFDownloadFileProtocol> file = [self getFileDownloadInfoIndexWithTaskIdentifier:_task.taskIdentifier];

            [file.downloadTask cancel];

            // Change all related properties.
            file.isDownloading = NO;
            file.taskIdentifier = -1;
            file.downloadProgress = 0.0;

        }

    }];

    cancel = YES;
}
```

Comment: Or just generate a UUID and store it in NSUserDefaults.  There's really no need to reuse the same session identifier.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

That is the expected behaviour, when you cancel tasks on a session they might still call the delegate method.

Have you check the state of the given task? It should be `NSURLSessionTaskStateCanceling`.

Comment: Please add code for getFileDownloadInfoIndexWithTaskIdentifier method