# How can I cancel all the NSMutableURLRequest during logout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsurlconnection

I am making HTTP request to server using `NSMutableURLRequest`. Now due to slow network it takes some time to get the response and in between I want to logout from my app. As multiple request is already sent to server before `logout` it will bring some response from server. I already logout from the app so I `don't want to process those response` and want to `cancel all the pending request` what all are there in the queue.

So how to stop getting all the response after logout?   Should I have to use some tag `logout` and check it ?

### Code Snippet :-

```
+(void) httpRequestWithUrl:(NSString *)path onComplection:(RequestCompletionHandler)complect {

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];

    NSOperationQueue *backgroundQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];


    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:backgroundQueue
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,NSData *data,NSError *error){
                           NSString *result = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                           if(complect)
                               complect(result,error);
                       }
     ];

}
```

### Edit:-

`What about AFNetworking ?`

Comment: You could use some kind of wrapper class that supports cancellation or use a session/logout tag like you mentioned.

Comment: Are you using an NSURLSession? This can be cancelled. Please show us some code so we can see how you are applying your URLRequest.

Comment: You can use `[connection cancel];` or cancel AFNetworking requests as outlined in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20638611/1445366). Notably, you can't cancel a *request*, you cancel a *URL connection* or *data task*.

Comment: @AaronBrager that will work for single operation right? how can I do for all the pending request and response ? what about NSMutableURLRequest?

Comment: Check this : [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];

Comment: @AaronBrager I know we can't cancel a http request but is there any mechanism to stop all the process,so that those connections will be aborted ?

Comment: You could store all of the `NSURLConnection` objects in an array, then call `[array makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(cancel)]`. But probably cleaner/better to just use operation queues (or AFNetworking, which has already done all of this work for you)

Comment: This is a good answer based on cancelling a NSURLSession
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975642/nsurlsession-cancel-task/27108324

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using NSURLSession instead of NSURLConnection.  It is designed specifically to make this easier.  Create a single session, and when the user logs out, call invalidateAndCancel on the existing session (and then log out in a separate session).

Really, the **only** valid reason to write **new** code based on NSURLConnection at this point is for supporting iOS 6 and earlier/OS X v10.8 and earlier, and it sounds like you're writing new code, so... please use the more modern APIs.