# How to cancel a URL session request

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I am upload multiple image to server using convert image to base64 and send image in a API as a parameter. But when we call api again and again then how to stop api calling on button click. I am using below code to call API.

Thanks in advance

```
let urlPath: String = "URL"
        let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
        var request1 = URLRequest(url: url)
        request1.httpMethod = "POST"
        let stringPost="imgSrc=\(image)"
        let data = stringPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        // print("data\(data)")
        request1.httpBody=data

        request1.timeoutInterval = 60
        let _:OperationQueue = OperationQueue()
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request1){data, response, err in
            do
            {
                if data != nil
                {
                    print("data\(String(describing: data))")
                    if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary
                    {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async
                            {
                        print("json\(jsonResult)")


                    }
                }

            }
            catch let error as NSError
            {
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                    {

                print("error is \(error)")
                print("error desc \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }}
        task.resume()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSURLSession cancel Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975642/nsurlsession-cancel-task)

Comment: Possible of duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23518690/how-to-find-and-cancel-a-task-in-nsurlsession

Answer (score 19):

Make the object `task` as a global variable, then you can cancel it anywhere by:

```
task.cancel()
```

Alternatively, if the object `session` is a `URLSession` instance, you can cancel it by:

```
session.invalidateAndCancel()
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to allow API call again if there is any previous download is on progress, you can do as follows,

Make your task(URLSessionDataTask type) variable as global variable in the class as follows,

```
let task = URLSessionDataTask()
```

Then on your button action do as below by checking the task download status,

```
func uploadButtonPressed() {
    if task.state != .running {
        // Make your API call here
    } else {
        // Dont perform API call
    }
}
```

You can make use following states like running which is provide by URLSessionDataTask class and do action accordingly as per your need,

```
public enum State : Int {
    case running
    case suspended
    case canceling
    case completed
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check result of your task. And if everything is alright you can

> task.resume()

but if not

> task.cancel()